# Mysql link to external resources: .zip an image file

Tags: mysql, filesystems

I really need your help: I have installed easphp on my laptop (apache, php, mysql).
I'm developing a db for mobile app (an online market)

I need to add a field that link an external file staying in a dir on my file system (cause now I'm working in locale).

I found some tutorial explaining how upload files into the db using the Blob type and MIME, but I would like my file staying in a folder and on the db have only some fields like, title, description, size, extension and one filed pointing to the file(the application .zip or some images .jpg in case i need some previews). I didn't find how to do that.

I don't have yet a php interface so I'm working only through phpmyadmin

1. What kind of type field should i use? Varchar, text........
2. Where should i store my file? In a generic folder c:\file or somewhere specific (inside apache folder or what else)
3. What should I insert in the field when i create a record with myphpmyadmin: the path? c:\bla bla bla simply?
4. Do I need other fields to menage later the file like the mime type or something else?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit [**Uploading Files To MySQL Database**](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx)

But it will be good if you store only path of the file in **DB**. And save file in directory. 
Link is here [**upload file with php and save path to sql**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879266/upload-file-with-php-and-save-path-to-sql)

**First and third answers are useful**